# Request in javascript (from python)

Tags: javascript, python, http, request

I have attempted to create a request in javascript, that has previously worked using python just fine.

the following is an accurate representation of the code I used to post the request with **python**:

```py
url = 'https://website.com/api/e1'
    
header = {
   'authorization': 'abcd1234'
}
payload = {
    'content': "text",
}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload,headers=header )
```

**This (above) works just fine in python.**

now what I did in **javascript** is the following:

```js
payload = {
    "content": "this is text",
  };
  fetch("https://website.com/api/e1", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "authorization":
        "abcd1234",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });
```

but this is returning the **error**
`400- Bad request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using data parameters on python requests.post, the default `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`(I couldn't find it on the document, but I checked the request. If you know, please leave a comment).

To achieve the same result with `fetch`, you must do as follows.

```js
const payload = {
  'content': 'this is text',
};
fetch('https://website.com/api/e1', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'authorization': 'abcd1234',
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams(payload),
});
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this `body: JSON.stringify(payload),` rather you can simply pass payload in body like this `body:payload`

Comment: Thanks, but that unfortunately does not help in fixing the error.